# Post a form inside bootstrap wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wizard which I create using bootstrapwizard using the below code

```
 $('#applicationWizard').bootstrapWizard({
        'tabClass': 'bwizard-steps',
        onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var $current = index + 1;
            var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
            $('#applicationWizard').find('.bar').css({ width: $percent + '%' });
        }
    });
```

Here's the view

```
        using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="row">
                <div id="applicationWizard" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section I</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section II</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Section III</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Section IV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Section V</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br />
                    <hr />
                    <div class="tab-content">                               
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                            <h3>Section I: General Information</h3>
                            <hr />
                            @Html.Partial("_General", Model)
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <h3>Section II: Aff Information</h3>
                            <hr />
                            @Html.Partial("_AffInformation", Model)
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                            <h3>Section III: Origination Information</h3>
                            <hr />
                            @Html.Partial("_Origination", Model)
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                            <h3>Section IV: Lending Information</h3>
                            <hr />
                            @Html.Partial("_LendingInformation", Model)
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                            <h3>Section V: Control</h3>
                            <hr />
                            @Html.Partial("_Control", Model)
                        </div>                
                        <hr />
                        <ul class="pager wizard">
                            <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a></li>
                            <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                            <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>
                            <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                            <li><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" class="cancel" /></li>
                            <li><input type="submit" name="SubmitApplication" value="Submit Application" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <br />
        }
```

The issue is when Submit is clicked it just validates the current tab and the data inside it and not the whole form. Can someone please tell me how I can make it validate the whole form instead of just one tab.

Thanks

Comment: change `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` and see if the validation errors appear

Comment: The validation errors appear but they are just for the active tab and not the whole form which included 4 other tabs.

Comment: Im not sure about the wizard you're using but you should be on the last page to see the `Submit` button and all previous tabs should have already been validated

Comment: We can save a partially incomplete form so I am not verifying each tab to be valid. I have the save button on all the tabs and then the submit on the last one but when I hit submit it just validates the last one and leaves the rest of the tabs.

Comment: but that's the intended functionality of a wizard.  `Submit` should only validate the last tab.  take a look at this, it may help you some to do what you want http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/

Comment: But what if I have wrong data say in the second tab. Is it not supposed to validate that data since I don't have tab to tab validation.

Comment: The issue is that in this example you cannot move to the second tab if first tab is not valid. In my case I can move freely from tab to tab and save incomplete data but the last  submit button is not supposed to call the server before it validates the client which it only does for one tab on which it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82733/discussion-between-jamied77-and-sp9).

Comment: I am getting a object is not supported when i add this .formValidation to $('#applicationWizard')